# Editting a single word or number inside a specific tagged string which exists within multiple .strings files

Tags: ios, string, replace, localizable.strings

I have multiple files in different languages which are localization files for IOS. I need to change a number (30) inside one of the strings that exists within all the files but there are multiple instances of 30 so I can't replace all.
Basically, is there a way to search the files, find the string enclosed by the tags I am looking for and change all instances of 30 within that to another value?

Answer (score 0):

You can do multi-file search and replace with regular expressions.  Use Find > "Find and Replace in Workspace ..."

Then, drop down the menu under the word "Text" in the "Replace > Text > Containing" control at the top of the Find navigator.

I can't tell you what regular expression to use. If you wanted something like this:

```
"<b>A bold 30</b>"
```

You could use a regular expression like (to change 30 to 40):

- Find: `(<b>.*)30([^<]*</b>)`
- Replace: `$140$2`